# jQuery: Isotope Set Rules on Shuffled Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

With Isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html), is there a way to specify that, even when shuffling the items, the `div` with the class `featured`, always be positioned at the top left most position of it's container?

**HTML**

```
<div class="item w2 h2 featured"></div>
<div class="item w1 h1></div>
<div class="item w3 h1></div>
<div class="item w2 h1></div>
```

**JS**

```
var $container = $('$container');

var isotope = function () {

    $container.isotope({
      resizable: false,
      itemSelector: '.item',

      masonry: {
        columnWidth: colWidth(),
        gutterWidth: 20
      }
    });
  };

isotope();

$window.smartresize( isotope );

$('#shuffle').click(function(){
    $container.isotope('shuffle');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [custom layout modes](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/extending-isotope.html#custom_layout_modes). Don't worry - it's quite simple and quick, I've done it myself.